# directory based idea project with gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I looked at the [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) and didn't see a way to do this. Is there a way to tell the gradle idea task to create the directory project structure (`.idea`) rather than the project/module files (`ipr, iml, iws`) ?

Comment: If it provided value to you, I suspect a pull request to add that feature would be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. IDEA 13 will ship with greatly improved Gradle support, at which point Gradle's `idea` tasks will likely become less important.

Comment: It's really not that important with 12.  I was just curious.  Thanks.

Comment: Here in the future with IDEA 15 and we're still using gradle idea to do this stuff because when we let IDEA do it, it breaks the project.

Comment: Agree. It's not sufficient for complex projects.

Comment: Just as an update, they are currently working on this: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1366